# innerHTML does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a "prediction game" just to gain experience in JavaScript, it's a game where you enter your football match prediction and it should tell you if you are right or wrong and post to the page the scorers and some match stats, my problem is that the innerHTML which should post the match stats refusing to work.

here is the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="he">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/StyleSheet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <title>Match Randomizer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <h1 id="title">Predict The Match Score!</h1>
        <div class="top">
        <img id="barcaLogo" src="Pics/Fc_barcelona.png" alt="logo">
        <img id="juveLogo" src="Pics/Juventus-logo.png" alt="logo">
        <form id="form">
            Barca:<input type="text" name="Barca" id="barcaPrediction"></br>
            Rival:<input type="text" name="Rival" id="rivalPrediction"></br>
            <input type="button" value="Show Me The Real Score!" onclick="scoreRandom()">
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
        <div id="barcaScorers" class="stats">Scorers:</div>
        <div id="stats" class="stats">Scorers:</div>
        <div id="juveScorers" class="stats">Scorers:</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/Script.js"></script>
</body>
```

and the JS code:

```
function scoreRandom()
{
    var barcaPrediction = document.getElementById('barcaPrediction');
    var rivalPrediction = document.getElementById('rivalPrediction');
    var barcaScore = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    var rivalScore = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    var barcaPlayers = ['M.ter Stegen','J.Alba','M.Bartra','D.Alves','G.Pique','Xavi','A.Iniesta','Sergio.B','Neymar','L.Suarez','L.Messi'];
    var barcaScorers = [];
    var timeGame = [];
    var timeStart = 0;
    var num;
    ////////////////////////////////
    ///Number randomizer function///
    ////////////////////////////////
    var randomNum = function(min , max)
    {
         num = Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);
         return num;
    };
    console.log(randomNum(1,5));
    ////////////////////////////////
    ///Checks if the form is empty//
    ////////////////////////////////
    if(barcaPrediction.value === '' || rivalPrediction.value === ''||barcaPrediction.value === isNaN || rivalPrediction.value === isNaN)
    { alert('Please enter your prediction!'); }

    document.getElementById('form').innerHTML = '<h1>' + barcaScore + ' - ' + rivalScore + '</h1>';

    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    ///Checks if your guess is right or wrong//
    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    if(barcaScore === barcaPrediction.value && rivalScore === rivalPrediction.value)
        document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = '<h1>You were right!</h1>';
    else
        document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = '<h1>You were wrong!</h1>';

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///Pushing the scorers from barcaPlaers array//
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
   for (var i = 0; i < barcaScore; i++ )
    {
        barcaScorers.push(barcaPlayers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)]);
        rand_number = Math.floor(Math.random()*90+1);
        timeGame.push(rand_number);
        for (var j = 0; j < barcaScore; j++)
        {
            barcaScorers.push(barcaPlayers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10+1)]);
        }
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///Sorting the time from small to big, and outputing it with the scorers names//
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    timeGame.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
   for (i=0; i < timeGame.length; i++){
             document.getElementById("barcaScorers").innerHTML += '<p>'+barcaScorers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)]+' '+timeGame[i]+"'</p>";
}
    ////////////////////////////
    ///RANDOMIZING MATCH STATS//
    ////////////////////////////
    var shots = randomNum(barcaScore, 20);
    var shotsOnTarget = randomNum(barcaScore, shots);
    var possesion;
    var tackles = randomNum(0, 15);
    var fouls = randomNum(tackles, 20);
    var yellowCards = randomNum(tackles, fouls);
    var redCards = randomNum(yellowCards, 3);
    var offsides = randomNum(0, barcaScore);
    var corners = randomNum(0,shots);


    document.getElementById("stats").innerHTML += '<p> Shots:' + shots + 'Shots on target: ' + shotsOnTarget + '</p>';

}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: `does not work` is not a very helpful description of your problem. See  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It does not post the match stats to the page

Comment: @AlphaCode I'm sure you can do better than that. Any errors on the console? Did you do any debugging? `console.log()` to make sure your code is getting called with the right value?

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: Granted i don't have your style-sheets, everything seems to be working on my local server.

Comment: Yes, everything seems to be fine, however I don`t get the wanted result.

Comment: what would be wanted result?

Comment: @AlphaCode what is the result you want?  Maybe make a fiddle we can reference.

Comment: @AlphaCode It seems to work as intended http://jsfiddle.net/an5hbLnd/ You may not be loading your JS file, check your console for errors. Please read our suggestions on how to describe your problem instead of just repeating: `does not work`. How on earth are we supposed to know what that means? Put some effort into your question. Do some actual debugging.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jsyqe4fh/

Comment: your function is working fine, may be you should look into the calculations you have done if you dont get desired result

Answer (score 0):

```
if(barcaScore === barcaPrediction.value && rivalScore === rivalPrediction.value)
```

Since `barcaScore` and `rivalScore` are integers and values from the input are string, you need to change it to:

```
if(barcaScore === parseInt(barcaPrediction.value) && rivalScore === parseInt(rivalPrediction.value))
```

or change `===` to `==`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because it crash when displaying the barca scorers. This is due to the way you put your scorers in the array.

Seeing your code I would rather make a structure storing scorers and time together in the barcaScorers array.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////
///Pushing the scorers from barcaPlaers array//
///////////////////////////////////////////////
for (var i = 0; i < barcaScore; i++ )
{
    var newBarcaScorers = {};
    newBarcaScorers.time = Math.floor(Math.random()*90+1);
    newBarcaScorers.player = barcaPlayers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
    barcaScorers.push(newBarcaScorers);
}
```

So you can display them efficiently afterward like this:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///Sorting the time from small to big, and outputing it with the scorers names//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
barcaScorers.sort(function(a, b){return a.time > b.time});
for (i=0; i < barcaScorers.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("barcaScorers").innerHTML += '<p>'+barcaScorers[i].player+' '+barcaScorers[i].time+"'</p>";
}
```